# Redirect issue with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I am trying to add a redirect in my `.htaccess` file and Im struggling with the `+` signs in the URLs.

Here's my redirect entry in my `.htaccess` file

```
Redirect 301 "^http://www.emfs.info/glossary/glossary+c.htm$" "http://www.emfs.info/glossary-2/"
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: The plus is parsed as a regexp "keyword" and has to be escaped by `\`

Answer (score 1):

1. The [`Redirect` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) does not accept regex patterns.
2. The patterns need not be enclosed in quotes.
3. If all the rules are for the same host `emfs.info`, then you don't need to use entire URL structure.
4. Make sure that `mod_alias` is being loaded.

Give a try to [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch):

```
RedirectMatch permanent /?glossary/glossary+c.htm$ /glossary-2/
```

Put this inside the `.htaccess` file in your document root. If you want another method using `mod_rewrite`, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.emfs\.info$
RewriteRule ^/?glossary/glossary\+c.htm$ /glossary-2/ [R=301,L]
```

Put this inside `htaccess` file at the same location.

Comment: Thanks for this, very much appreciated! I managed to find a WP plugin that manipulates the + signs in URLS. I'm going to give this a go too though. nice one!